# Firebase Firestore: Add data to field once, even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a quiz application using Vue.JS and firebase and I have ran into a bit of a problem.

I need the score from the quiz to be added to my Firestore database which I can do this easy with the following code:

```
var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('userData').doc(this.userIdSelf)
firebase.firestore().runTransaction(function(transaction){
    return transaction.get(docRef).then(function(doc) {
        if (!doc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }
        var newScore = doc.data().score + app.user.score;
        transaction.update(docRef, { score: newScore });
        return newScore;
    });
}).then(function(newScore) {
    console.log("Success! Score updated to: "+newScore);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

This code will run on the final leaderboard of the quiz (when the quiz has finished).
The issue i'm having, and this might be me being really stupid, is that I only need this code to run once when the user loads the page. The code can't run again on refresh.

• How would I make this code only run once?

• Would I implement this just using vue.js/javascript or does firebase have something built in which I don't know about?

• Finally, should I execute the above code in a function or on created()?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that you execute the update in a Transaction. Just add an extra field to the `userData` document, indicating that the update has been done and check this field in the transaction.

Something along the following lines, where `finalLeaderboardUpdated` is the extra field mentioned above and is a boolean.

```
  var docRef = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('userData')
    .doc(this.userIdSelf);

  firebase
    .firestore()
    .runTransaction(function (transaction) {
      return transaction.get(docRef).then(function (doc) {
        if (!doc.exists) {
          throw 'Document does not exist!';
        }

        if (doc.data().finalLeaderboardUpdated) {
          // finalLeaderboardUpdated is true, meaning the doc was already updated with the newScore
          return Promise.reject("Final Leaderboard already Updated");
        } else {
          var newScore = doc.data().score + app.user.score;
          transaction.update(docRef, {
            score: newScore,
            finalLeaderboardUpdated: true,   // Here we set finalLeaderboardUpdated to true
          });
          return newScore;
        } 
      });
    })
    .then(function (newScore) {
      console.log('Success! Score updated to: ' + newScore);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Deal with the rejected promise here: e.g. show a message to the user
      console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I assume I just change it back to false before the next game starts!

Comment: "I assume I just change it back to false before the next game starts! " => Yes, up to you you to change it back depending on the exact "flow" of your game. You should probably use a Transaction as well for that (again, depending on your exact use case).