# Using Cell table, sum of all values ​in firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firestore file, all files add the value of the field "quantity" (all together and displayed in the label)[image]

For example, the value of "Quantity" in the first file field is "1", the value of "Quantity" in the second file field is "2", and the value of "Quantity" in the third file field is "2.3"" 1+2+2.3= Displayed in the label: 5.3 as shown in Figure 2

But Form 2 automatically changes X2 to 10.6

Form three becomes 15.9

Only 5.3 in Table 1 is correct, why?

Here is my code[image]

```
db.collection("Admin").document("AI智能機器人").collection("Ai日獲利")
                //.order(by: "date", descending: true)
                //.whereField("date", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateStr)
                //.whereField("date", isLessThanOrEqualTo: date3)
                .getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
                    if snapshot!.documents.isEmpty  {
                        
                        
                    }else{
                        if snapshot?.isEmpty != true && snapshot != nil {
                        
                        for document in snapshot!.documents{
                            
                            if let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double{
                                self.totalVotes += quantity
                                
                                cell.nowq8.text = "+"+String(format: "%.4f", self.totalVotes)+"%"
                                print("quantity:\(self.totalVotes)")[![enter image description here][3]][3]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

"quantity" sliding tableview will continue to accumulate, what should I do? It has troubled me for a long time.. A little help is greatly appreciated![image]

Comment: This probably seems due to missing checks on Snapshot, which result in those getting executed again and again and thus sum up when the next form is called.You can veify this at your end how many times it is called by adding console statements.If you so you may try to eliminate these repeat snapshot calls and check what you get.

Comment: May I ask what code should I add to improve it? This has troubled me for a long time. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Firestore listeners by design are made such that you will always be delivered the document(s) relevant to the fetch or query and the updates as long as the lisenter remain active,which results in multiple read and call fo the function that results in adding up of field value with every refresh and update call.There is no mode to receive deltas only.
The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query. This is because you're getting a set of changes that bring your query snapshot current with the initial state of the query.So each time you refresh your page you are calling again the onSnapshot() method "from scratch" and therefore you get the logic added to in every next run.
**Updated**

```
db.collection("Admin").document("AI智能機器人").collection("Ai日獲利")
            .getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    if snapshot.documents.isEmpty  {
                        // Handle the case where there are no documents
                    } else {
                        for document in snapshot.documents {
                            if(document?.data())
                                let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double {
                                self.totalVotes += quantity
                                cell.nowq8.text = "+"+String(format: "%.4f", self.totalVotes)+"%"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle the error
                }
            }
```

Also do checkout these links for similar implementations:

- [Firestore document is read multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544937/firestore-document-is-read-multiple-times-after-a-single-update-in-firebase-emul)
- [Updating same document twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60945044/cloud-firestore-does-updating-the-same-document-twice-in-a-batch-count-as-a-sin)
- [Add data to field once even after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64736912/firebase-firestore-add-data-to-field-once-even-after-page-refresh)

Comment: if let docu = document,  An error occurred"Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'"

Comment: I still don't quite understand.. sorry I only learn swift, thank you very much for your guidance

Comment: I have updated the code in the answer above, please check.

Comment: " if (document.data())" An error occurred "Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected condition type 'Bool'"，"let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double {"An error occurred"Computed property must have an explicit type"，Thanks for your help, but same error..

Comment: Try and replace 
`if(document?.data())
                                let quantity = document.data()["quantity"] as? Double {
                                self.totalVotes += quantity
                                cell.nowq8.text = "+"+String(format: "%.4f", self.totalVotes)+"%"
  }`
 to
 `if let data = document.data(), let quantity = data["quantity"] as? Double {
    self.totalVotes += quantity
    cell.nowq8.text = "+"+String(format: "%.4f", self.totalVotes)+"%"
}`

Comment: if let data = document.data(),  mistake  Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'

Comment: Still can't solve the problem.. can you help me?